# Crear un estilo concreto por medio del render() del zebra form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

Éste es mi código:

```
//Todos los permisos a contratar a continuacion, y todos ellos vendran como no mostrados 
// Permisos del area social y sus partes
$form->add('label', 'label_SOCIAL', 'SOCIAL', 'ÁREA SOCIAL');   
//contactos
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialContactos', 'permisos_social_contactos', 'Contactos:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_contactos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Enseres
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialEnseres', 'permisos_social_enseres', 'Enseres:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_enseres',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Medico
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialMedico', 'permisos_social_medico', 'Medico:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_medico',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Personal
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialPersonal', 'permisos_social_personal', 'Personal:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_personal',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Prestaciones
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialPrestaciones', 'permisos_social_prestaciones', 'Prestaciones:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_prestaciones',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Seguimientos
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialSeguimiento', 'permisos_social_seguimiento', 'Seguimientos:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_seguimiento',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Urgencias
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialUrgencias', 'permisos_social_urgencias', 'Urgencias:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_urgencias',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));










// Permisos area economica
$form->add('label', 'label_ECO', 'ECO', 'ÁREA ECONÓMICA');
//Cuentas
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaCuentas', 'permisos_economica_cuentas', 'Cuentas:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_cuentas',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaIngresos', 'permisos_economica_ingresos', 'Ingresos:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_ingresos',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//obligaciones
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaObligaciones', 'permisos_economica_obligaciones', 'Obligaciones:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_obligaciones',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Seguros
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaSeguros', 'permisos_economica_seguros', 'Seguros:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_seguros',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));






// Permisos area juridica
$form->add('label', 'label_JURIDICA', 'JURIDICA', 'ÁREA JURIDICA');
//Fechas
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaFechas', 'permisos_juridica_fechas', 'Fechas:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_fechas',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//autorizaciones judiciales
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaJudiciales', 'permisos_juridica_judiciales', 'Autorizaciones:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_judiciales',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Juzgado
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaJuzgados', 'permisos_juridica_juzgado', 'Juzgados:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_juzgado',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//Retribuccion
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaRetribuccion', 'permisos_juridica_retribucion', 'Retribuccion:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_retribucion',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));




// Permisos voluntariado
$form->add('label', 'label_VOLUN', 'COLL', 'ÁREA VOLUNTARIADO');
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosVoluntariado', 'permisos_voluntariado', 'Voluntariado:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_voluntariado',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));





// Permisos listado
$form->add('label', 'label_Lisrtado', 'listado', 'AREA LISTADO');
//Informes
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoInformes', 'permisos_listado_informes', 'Informes:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_informes',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//juzgado
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoJuzgado', 'permisos_listado_juzgados', 'Juzgado:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_juzgados',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

//residencias
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoResidencias', 'permisos_listado_residencia', 'Residencias:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_residencia',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));





// Permisos SAOS
$form->add('label', 'label_SAOS', 'SAOS', 'ÁREA SAOS');
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosSAOS', 'permisos_saos', 'SAOS:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_saos',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));



// Permisos expedientes
$form->add('label', 'label_EXPEDIENTE', 'EXPEDIENTE', 'ÁREA EXPEDIENTES');
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosExpedientes', 'permisos_expedientes', 'Expedientes:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_expedientes',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));





// Permisos de campo administracion propia
$form->add('label', 'label_ADMIN', 'ADMIN', 'ÁREA ADMINISTRACIÓN');
$form->add('label', 'label_permisosAdministracion', 'permisos_administracion', 'Administracion:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_administracion',
array(
    '0' => si,
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

// Permisos de ver datos de pacientes
$form->add('label', 'label_Paciente', 'Paciente', 'SECCIÓN PACIENTE SELECCIONADO');
//boton de subida

$form->add('label', 'label_datTrasladoPaciente', 'datTrasladoPaciente', 'Datos Traslados Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'datTrasladoPaciente',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_datPersonalPaciente', 'datPersonalPaciente', 'Datos Personales Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'datPersonalPaciente',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_datResidenciaPaciente', 'datResidencialPaciente', 'Datos Domicilio Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'datResidencialPaciente',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_pacienteMedicos', 'pacienteMedicos', 'Datos Medicos Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'pacienteMedicos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_medicamentos', 'medicamentos', 'Medicamentos Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'medicamentos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_citas', 'citas', 'Citas Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'citas',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_hospitalizaciones', 'hospitalizaciones', 'Hospitalizaciones Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'hospitalizaciones',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_cirugias', 'cirugias', 'Cirugias Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'cirugias',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_dependencia', 'dependencia', 'Dependencia Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'dependencia',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);  
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_acompañamientos', 'acompañamientos', 'Acompañamientos Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'acompañamientos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

    $form->add('label', 'label_otrasPrestaciones', 'otrasPrestaciones', 'Otras Prestaciones Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'otrasPrestaciones',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_catering', 'catering', 'Catering Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'catering',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_teleasistencia', 'teleasistencia', 'Teleasistencia Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'teleasistencia',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_prestaciones', 'prestaciones', 'Prestaciones Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'prestaciones',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_publicaResidencial', 'publicaResidencial', 'Plaza Publica Residencial del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'publicaResidencial',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_pedidos', 'pedidos', 'Pedidos del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'pedidos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_objetosValor', 'objetosValor', 'Objetos de Valor Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'objetosValor',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_ropa', 'ropa', 'Ropa del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'ropa',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_pensiones', 'pensiones', 'Pensiones del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'pensiones',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_alquileres', 'alquileres', 'Alquileres del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'alquileres',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_expedienteJudgado', 'expedienteJudgado', 'Expediente Judgado del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'expedienteJudgado',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('label', 'label_judgadoDatos', 'judgadoDatos', 'Datos Judgado del Paciente:');
$obj = $form->add('radios', 'judgadoDatos',
array(
    '0' => si,      
    '1' => no
)

);
$obj->set_rule(array(
    'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
));

$form->add('submit', 'btn_submit', 'Guardar'); 
$form->render('*Especial');
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a conseguir crear el documento Especial para que la vista quede de la siguiente forma?:

```
AREA SOCIAL

contactos si  enseres si medicos si personal si prestaciones si seguimiento si
          no          no         no          no              no             no
urgencias si
          no

AREA ECONOMICA

cuenta si ingresios si obligaciones si seguros si
       no           no              no         no

AREA JURIDICA

fechas si autorizaciones si  judgado si autorizacion si
       no                no          no              no
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir imágenes de cómo se ve ahora mismo y cómo quieres que se vea?

Comment: No puedo subir imagenes pero esta todo en linea vertical y deseo poner  una cabecera llamada AREA SOCIAL y debajo de ella sus 7 subapartados con las dos opciones de si o no, despues otra cabecera de texto que pone solo AREA ECONOMICA y debajo de esta sus 5 subapartados con las opciones si y no. todo esta hecho con label y botones tipo radio en zebra_form como en el codigo anteriormente puesto

Comment: Me he descargado Zebra Form y he probado el código de arriba (añadiendo algunas cosas que faltaban), pero recibo el error "Zebra_Form could not automatically determine the correct path to the "process.php" and "mimes.json" files - this may happen if the script is run on a virtual host. To fix this, use the assets_path() method and manually set the correct server path and URL to these file!". ¿Sabes si falta algo más en el código? ¿o si hace falta algún fichero más aparte de lo que tienes puesto en la pregunta?

Comment: Solucioné ese problema, y ahora me da otro: "include(*Especial): failed to open stream" y "Failed opening '*Especial' for inclusion".

Comment: Estoy teniendo problemas para reproducir el problema en local, pero sinceramente, parece que lo que quieres no requiere ningún cambio en PHP sino en los estilos CSS. Comparte el código del formulario generado por Zebra y seguramente sea más fácil ayudarte de esa manera.

Comment: Esta tarde añado todo el codigo para que puedas ayudarme

Comment: Ya he subido el codigo a ver si peudes ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 0):

```
// Nombre de la web si deseamos cambiarlo
    $form->add('label', 'label_nombre', 'nombre_web', 'Nombre web:');
    $obj = $form->add('text', 'nombre_web', '', array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required'  =>  array('error', '¡Introduzca el nombre!'),
    ));


    //Todos los permisos a contratar a continuacion, y todos ellos vendran como no mostrados 
    // Permisos del area social y sus partes
    $form->add('label', 'label_SOCIAL', 'SOCIAL', 'ÁREA SOCIAL');   
    //contactos
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialContactos', 'permisos_social_contactos', 'Contactos:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_contactos',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Enseres
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialEnseres', 'permisos_social_enseres', 'Enseres:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_enseres',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Medico
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialMedico', 'permisos_social_medico', 'Medico:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_medico',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Personal
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialPersonal', 'permisos_social_personal', 'Personal:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_personal',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Prestaciones
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialPrestaciones', 'permisos_social_prestaciones', 'Prestaciones:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_prestaciones',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Seguimientos
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialSeguimiento', 'permisos_social_seguimiento', 'Seguimientos:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_seguimiento',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Urgencias
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSocialUrgencias', 'permisos_social_urgencias', 'Urgencias:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_social_urgencias',
    array(
        '0' => si,      
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));










    // Permisos area economica
    $form->add('label', 'label_ECO', 'ECO', 'ÁREA ECONÓMICA');
    //Cuentas
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaCuentas', 'permisos_economica_cuentas', 'Cuentas:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_cuentas',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaIngresos', 'permisos_economica_ingresos', 'Ingresos:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_ingresos',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //obligaciones
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaObligaciones', 'permisos_economica_obligaciones', 'Obligaciones:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_obligaciones',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Seguros
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosEconomicaSeguros', 'permisos_economica_seguros', 'Seguros:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_economica_seguros',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));






    // Permisos area juridica
    $form->add('label', 'label_JURIDICA', 'JURIDICA', 'ÁREA JURIDICA');
    //Fechas
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaFechas', 'permisos_juridica_fechas', 'Fechas:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_fechas',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //autorizaciones judiciales
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaJudiciales', 'permisos_juridica_judiciales', 'Autorizaciones:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_judiciales',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Juzgado
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaJuzgados', 'permisos_juridica_juzgado', 'Juzgados:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_juzgado',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //Retribuccion
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosJuridicaRetribuccion', 'permisos_juridica_retribucion', 'Retribuccion:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_juridica_retribucion',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));




    // Permisos voluntariado
    $form->add('label', 'label_VOLUN', 'COLL', 'ÁREA VOLUNTARIADO');
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosVoluntariado', 'permisos_voluntariado', 'Voluntariado:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_voluntariado',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));





    // Permisos listado
    $form->add('label', 'label_Lisrtado', 'listado', 'AREA LISTADO');
    //Informes
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoInformes', 'permisos_listado_informes', 'Informes:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_informes',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //juzgado
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoJuzgado', 'permisos_listado_juzgados', 'Juzgado:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_juzgados',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));

    //residencias
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosListadoResidencias', 'permisos_listado_residencia', 'Residencias:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_listado_residencia',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));





    // Permisos SAOS
    $form->add('label', 'label_SAOS', 'SAOS', 'ÁREA SAOS');
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosSAOS', 'permisos_saos', 'SAOS:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_saos',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));



    // Permisos expedientes
    $form->add('label', 'label_EXPEDIENTE', 'EXPEDIENTE', 'ÁREA EXPEDIENTES');
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosExpedientes', 'permisos_expedientes', 'Expedientes:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_expedientes',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));





    // Permisos de campo administracion propia
    $form->add('label', 'label_ADMIN', 'ADMIN', 'ÁREA ADMINISTRACIÓN');
    $form->add('label', 'label_permisosAdministracion', 'permisos_administracion', 'Administracion:');
    $obj = $form->add('radios', 'permisos_administracion',
    array(
        '0' => si,
        '1' => no
    )

    );
    $obj->set_rule(array(
        'required' => array('error', '¡Introduzca el permiso!')
    ));


    //boton de subida   
    $form->add('submit', 'btn_submit', 'Guardar');


    // Si el formulario se valida
    if ($form->validate()) {

        $f_social_contactos = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_contactos']);
        $f_social_enseres = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_enseres']);
        $f_social_medico = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_medico']);
        $f_social_personal = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_personal']);
        $f_social_prestaciones = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_prestaciones']);
        $f_social_seguimiento = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_seguimiento']);
        $f_social_urgencias = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_social_urgencias']);
        $f_economica_cuentas = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_economica_cuentas']);
        $f_economica_ingresos = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_economica_ingresos']);
        $f_economica_obligaciones = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_economica_obligaciones']);
        $f_economica_seguros = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_economica_seguros']);
        $f_expedientes = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_expedientes']);
        $f_saos = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_saos']);
        $f_juridica_fechas = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_juridica_fechas']);
        $f_juridica_judiciales = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_juridica_judiciales']);
        $f_juridica_juzgado = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_juridica_juzgado']);
        $f_juridica_retribucion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_juridica_retribucion']);
        $f_administracion = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_administracion']);
        $f_listado_residencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_listado_residencia']);
        $f_listado_juzgados = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_listado_juzgados']);
        $f_listado_informes = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_listado_informes']);
        $f_voluntariado = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['permisos_voluntariado']);
        $f_nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli_handle, $_POST['nombre_web']);

        $query = "UPDATE websAdministradas SET
            nombre_web = '$f_nombre', 
            permisos_social_contactos = '$f_social_contactos',
            permisos_social_prestaciones = '$f_social_prestaciones',
            permisos_social_seguimiento = '$f_social_seguimiento',
            permisos_social_urgencias = '$f_social_urgencias',
            permisos_social_enseres = '$f_social_enseres',
            permisos_social_medico = '$f_social_medico',
            permisos_social_personal= '$f_social_personal',
            permisos_economica_cuentas = '$f_economica_cuentas',
            permisos_economica_ingresos = '$f_economica_ingresos',
            permisos_economica_obligaciones = '$f_economica_obligaciones',
            permisos_economica_seguros = '$f_economica_seguros',
            permisos_saos = '$f_saos',
            permisos_juridica_judiciales = '$f_juridica_judiciales',
            permisos_juridica_fechas = '$f_juridica_fechas',
            permisos_juridica_juzgado = '$f_juridica_juzgado',
            permisos_juridica_retribucion = '$f_juridica_retribucion',
            permisos_administracion = '$f_administracion',
            permisos_voluntariado = '$f_voluntariado',
            permisos_expedientes = '$f_expedientes',
            permisos_listado_informes = '$f_listado_informes',
            permisos_listado_juzgados = '$f_listado_juzgados',
            permisos_listado_residencia = '$f_listado_residencia'
        WHERE id_web = $id_web;";

        $res = mysqli_query($mysqli_handle, $query);
        if ($res) {

            // Como ya se ha mandado la cabecera no podemos redirigir con "Location:"
            echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.location.href="index.php?sec=man_configurar_mostrar&ok=editar";</script>';
            exit;

        }else{
            $form->add_error('err_mysql', 'Error al guardar, inténtelo de nuevo.');
        }

    }

    $form->render('*horizontal');
```

Comment: Supongo que éste es el código que decías que ibas a compartir, por lo que no es una respuesta, sino que debería añadirse como edición a la pregunta. También, si es posible, pon el código HTML generado, no el PHP/Zebra.

Comment: he subido el html aunque falta una parte ya que es muy largo , si me ayudas seria increible

Comment: Alvaro podrias darme un correo de contacto para que me puedas ayudar , si es posible

Answer (score 0):

Leave this field blankNombre web:*ÁREA SOCIALContactos:*sinoEnseres:*sinoMedico:*sinoPersonal:*sinoPrestaciones:*sinoSeguimientos:*sinoUrgencias:*sinoÁREA ECONÓMICACuentas:*sinoIngresos:*sinoObligaciones:*sinoSeguros:*sinoÁREA JURIDICAFechas:*sinoAutorizaciones:*sinoJuzgados:*sinoRetribuccion:*sinoÁREA VOLUNTARIADOVoluntariado:*sinoAREA LISTADOInformes:*sinoJuzgado:*sinoResidencias:*sinoÁREA SAOSSAOS:*sinoÁREA EXPEDIENTESExpedientes:*sinoÁREA ADMINISTRACIÓNAdministracion:*sinoSECCIÓN PACIENTE SELECCIONADODatos Traslados Paciente:*sinoDatos Personales Paciente:*sinoDatos Domicilio Paciente:*sinoDatos Medicos Paciente:*sinoMedicamentos Paciente:*sinoCitas Paciente:*sinoHospitalizaciones Paciente:*sinoCirugias Paciente:*sinoDependencia Paciente:*sinoAcompañamientos Paciente:*sinoOtras Prestaciones Paciente:*sinoCatering Paciente:*sinoTeleasistencia Paciente:*sinoPrestaciones Paciente:*sinoPlaza Publica Residencial del Paciente:*sinoPedidos del Paciente:*sinoObjetos de Valor Paciente:*sinoRopa del Paciente:*sinoPensiones del Paciente:*...